# Angular js : resolve dependency route

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have $scope.question which has questions for all the page.

I want to loop through page wise questions. for this I wrote a function questionsCtrl. This function I am calling in config while setting route.

but here I am getting undefined.

Please suggest how to get data for page from $scope.questions.
app.js

```
 (function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("autoQuote",["ui.router","ngResource"]);

    app.config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider", function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
            .state("step1", {
              url : "",
              controller: "questionsCtrl",
            resolve: {
                pageQuestion: $scope.questions
            }
            })  
            .state("step2", {
              url : "/step2",
              controller: "questionsCtrl",
            })
    }]
    );
}());
```

questionCtrl.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
    .module("autoQuote")
    .controller("questionsCtrl",["$scope","$state","$q",questionsCtrl]);

    function questionsCtrl($scope,$state,$q) {
       console.log('here in get question for page: '+$state.current.name);
        //var deferred = $q.defer();
        if($state.current.name == "" || $state.current.name == "step1")
            {
                $scope.pageQuestion = $scope.RC1_Cars_v2;
            }
        else if($state.current.name == "step2")
            {
                $scope.pageQuestion = $scope.RC1_Drivers_v2;
            }
        //return deferred.promise;
        console.log($scope);
    }
}());
```

html

```
    <div class="container-fluid col-md-8">
    <div ng-controller="autoQuoteCtrl">

       <div ng-repeat="que in pageQuestion">
           <!-- pagequestion will be in loop here -->
       </div>


      </div>
    </div>
```

here is my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/kLc6DPqzQgLNpUBaLtZi?p=preview for complete code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller for a view contains view specific logic. If you add a template to your states via `template` or `templateUrl` you will have access to your controller's scope within that template. As far as I understand your problem you want to provide data to your content before the state is being displayed. If you take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) the resolve property is exactly what you are looking for:

> You can use resolve to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. resolve is an optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.

However, you are using it incorrectly. You won't have access to `$scope` in a `config` block. What you have to do is provide a function to your resolve property as follows:

```
resolve: {
  pageQuestion: function(myService) {
    return myService.getData();
  }
}
```

As you can see in the code snippet above, I am using a function which injects a service called `myService`. The service is responsible for getting your data. In the example I assume that the service has a method `getData` which returns a promise. The ui-router will now wait for all promises to be resolved before showing the state. Once you have created such function, you can use the name of your resolve property (in this case `pageQuestion`) to inject your data into your view controller. So your question controller would look like this:

```
function questionsCtrl(pageQuestion) {
  this.pageQuestion = pageQuestion;
}
```

You simply inject your resolve into your controller and assign it to a view variable.

Notice, that I am assuming the `controllerAs` syntax for your state, so I can ommit the `$scope` and directly use `this` inside the controller. All you have to do is to add a property `controllerAs` to your state configuration as follows:

```
.state("step1", {
  ...
  controller: "questionsCtrl",
  controllerAs: 'vm'         
})
```

This has the advantage, that you won't run into scope problems (this has something to do with scope inheritance) in the long run. [This](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) is a great article on scopes.

Your view should look like this now:

```
<div class="container-fluid col-md-8">
  <div ng-repeat="que in vm.pageQuestion">
    <!-- pagequestion will be in loop here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you access your data via `vm`, which comes from the `controllerAs` property in your state config. I would also suggest to use the template for your state and remove occurrences of `ng-controller`. You won't be needing this because you have a view controller declared for your state already. Additionally, `ng-controller`'s make it difficult to propertly manage your state. You end up with a scope soup, and this is something you definietly want to avoid.

Comment: thanks for detailed answer. I updated app.js and questionResource.js in plunker. but getting error.

Comment: Indeed, you have many errors in your Plunker. How about you create a new Plunker from scratch and add only those things you really need to get your resolve working, meaning a service to fetch your data, a router configuraton, templates and a controller.